# CSS3 and Menu Item Highlighting

Tags: css, html

I am trying to make a simple sidebar menu that has its menu item styled or highlighted when its linked page is currently viewed. I've been trying to make it as compact and simple as possible but I can't get the highlight/styled effect to work.

this is the code:

HTML

```
<div class="navmenu">
<ul class="navmenu1">
<li><a href="url1">home</a></li>
<li><a href="url2">about us</a></li>
<li><a href="url3">services</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="url3a">option 1</a></li>
<li><a href="url3b">option 2</a></li>
<li><a href="url3c">option 3</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a href="url4">contact us</a></li>
<li><a href="url5">gallery</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
.navmenu ul {
    margin:5px 0 0 0;
   padding:0;
   font:bold 13px verdana;
   width:250px;
}
.navmenu li a {
    margin-top:-5px;
    display:block;
    text-decoration:none;
    padding:14px 10px 16px;
    border-bottom:.5px dotted #cccccc;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out,;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out 0s;
}
.navmenu a:hover, .navmenu a:active {
    color:white;
    background-color:blue;
}
.navmenu li.menu-item.current_page_item > a, 
.navmenu li.menu-item.current-menu-item > a {
    color:green;
} 

/* submenu */
.navmenu ul li ul {
    margin-left:-1px;
    text-indent:20px;
}
```

I've been trying endlessly to get the current page/current menu item highlighted and nothing seems to work. I've tried different iterations of code with `.current-menu-item` and `.current_page_item` but nothing.

Comment: could you provide a link to the actual page?

Answer (score 1):

you can use the wordpress default class .current-menu-parent or current-menu-ancestor. the code worked for me is below. u just add those to your style.css.

```
.current-menu-parent a, .current-menu-ancestor a {

  color: #7dca8d;

    }
```

or you can try this also. this also worked for me.

```
.navmenu  .current-menu-ancestor > a {
background-color: #B44A52;
color: #fff;
}
```

so that when the submenu item page is visited its parent menu will be highlighted with red color.